# Spatial interpolation of 30 weather stations to other areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, climate, stata

I have monthly (and sometimes daily) data on temperatures from about 30 Swedish weather stations in the mid-19th century that I want interpolate to the whole country. I'm using ArcGIS and Stata.

For later years, I have data on additional weather stations (around 100), so I've thought of using the later data as to calibrate a model using the old stations to predict weather at the new stations. Since I know the actual weather at the new stations, I could calibrate to model to achieve the best possible fit. But I'm not sure what a good method for going about achieving a suitable fit (don't want to risk overfitting for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can likely get a reasonable interpolation using a linear regression (assuming your 30 weather stations are a representative sample) using elevation, latitude and distance from the coast as independent variables with the day as a factor.  I've done this  using ArcGIS and R previously.

[image: Daily 9am and 3pm temperatures over 10 days in 2003]

*Daily 9am and 3pm temperatures over 10 days in 2003 from weather stations in South Eastern Australia*

### Basic steps:

- Get a digital elevation model of your area.
- Get vector or raster coastline
- Generate a latitude raster ([example](http://arcgisandpython.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/latitude-longitude-rasters-in-arcgis-10.html))
- Generate a distance from coast raster (perhaps with [Euclidian Distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000))
- For the variables that you don't have data for for each station, use the [Sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002v000000) or [Extract Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_Values_to_Points/009z0000002t000000/) tool to query the relevant raster. I only needed to do this for distance from coast as my weather station data contained lon, lat and elevation.
- Plug elevation, lat and distance as independent variables, temperature as dependent variable and day as a factor into a linear regression model in r/spss/stata/etc...
- If you get a decent fit, use the model coefficients to create a raster calculator expression (`temp = α + βelev*elev + βlat*lat + βdist*dist`) to estimate temperature from elevation, lat and distance. You may need to script this as you'll get different coefficients for each day.